# Site Monitoring Utility can't connect to website even though site is up and working

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have created a Site Monitoring Utility, that sends an HTTP and PING request to a site, checks the database to make sure it's up and ready to take requests, and checks a service that the website needs.

The problem is, the utility will randomly lose connection to the server for hours at a time, with no reason why.

I have run WireShark multiple times on the server to see if there is something network related, but I keep coming up with nothing. WireShark says no packets or anything is getting dropped.

Has anybody else ever run into anything like that?

I can't post the code for the service, as it contains sensitive information in it. I don't think it's my code, but I'm having a hard time figuring out what it could be!

Here is my Code:

```csharp
private void HttpRequest()
{
    foreach(string urlToTest in urls)
    {
        bool Success = false;
        HttpWebResponse URLRes = null;
        HttpWebRequest URLReq = null;
        bool Timed = false;
        StringBuilder Message = null;

        HttpStatusCode code = HttpStatusCode.Unused;
        string codeDescript = string.Empty;

        for (int i = 0; i < HTTPThreshold; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                WriteToOwnEventLog("Sending HTTP Request to " + urlToTest, "Http Request", true);
                URLReq = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(urlToTest);
                URLReq.Timeout = 300000;
                URLReq.Proxy = null;
                URLReq.ServicePoint.ConnectionLeaseTimeout = 300000;
                URLReq.ServicePoint.MaxIdleTime = 300000;
                URLReq.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
                URLReq.AuthenticationLevel = System.Net.Security.AuthenticationLevel.None;
                ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;

                using(URLRes = (HttpWebResponse) URLReq.GetResponse())
                {
                    if (URLReq.HaveResponse)
                    {
                        if (URLRes.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK || URLRes.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Continue)
                        {
                            Success = true;
                            Timed = false;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                if (URLRes != null && URLRes.StatusCode != null)
                    code = URLRes.StatusCode;

                if (URLRes != null && URLRes.StatusDescription != null)
                    codeDescript = URLRes.StatusDescription;

                if (ex.Message == "The operation has timed out")
                {
                    Timed = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    LogError(ex);
                    if (i + 1 == HTTPThreshold)
                    {
                        Message = new StringBuilder("Message: " + ex.Message + "<br/>");

                        if (ex.InnerException != null)
                            Message.Append("Inner Exception: " + ex.InnerException + "<br/>");

                        if (ex.Source != null)
                            Message.Append("Source: " + ex.Source + "<br/>");

                        if (ex.StackTrace != null)
                            Message.Append("Stack Trace" + ex.StackTrace + "<br/>");
                    }
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                if (URLReq != null)
                {
                    URLReq.Abort();
                    URLReq = null;
                }

                if (URLRes != null)
                {
                    URLRes.Close();
                    URLRes = null;
                }

                GC.Collect();
            }
        }

        if (Success)
        {
            WriteToOwnEventLog("HTTP Request returned Successful", "Http Request", true);
        }
        else
        {
            if (!Timed && code != HttpStatusCode.Unused && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(codeDescript) && Message == null)
                EmailError("Site '" + urlToTest + "' HttpRequest returned with a status of " + code.ToString() + ". \n Description: \n " + codeDescript);
            else if (!Timed && code != HttpStatusCode.Unused && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(codeDescript) && Message != null)
                EmailError("Site '" + urlToTest + "' errored with an exception. HttpRequest returned with a status of " + code.ToString() + ". \n Description: \n " + codeDescript + Message.ToString());
            else if (!Timed && code == HttpStatusCode.Unused && string.IsNullOrEmpty(codeDescript) && Message == null)
                EmailError("Site '" + urlToTest + "' HttpRequest returned with Error. No information to display");
            else if (!Timed && code == HttpStatusCode.Unused && string.IsNullOrEmpty(codeDescript) && Message != null)
                EmailError("Site '" + urlToTest + "' HTTPRequest errored with an exception.<br/>" + Message.ToString());
            else if (Timed)
                EmailError("Site '" + urlToTest + "' HTTPRequest Timed Out");

            WriteToOwnEventLog("HTTP Request failed, Email Sent", "Http Request", true);
        }

    }

    WriteToOwnEventLog("<--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->", "Http Request", false);
}

private void PingUrl()
{
    foreach(string urlToTest in urls)
    {
        bool Success = false;
        PingReply reply = null;
        StringBuilder Message = null;
        IPStatus status = IPStatus.Unknown;
        for (int i = 0; i < PingThreshold; i++)
        {
            Ping ping = null;
            try
            {
                ping = new Ping();

                WriteToOwnEventLog("Ping sent to " + urlToTest, "Ping", true);

                string urlToTest1 = urlToTest.Substring(urlToTest.IndexOf(":") + 3);
                if (urlToTest1.Contains('/'))
                {
                    urlToTest1 = urlToTest1.Substring(0, urlToTest1.IndexOf('/'));
                }
                reply = ping.Send(urlToTest1);

                status = reply.Status;

                if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
                {
                    Success = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                LogError(ex);
                if (i + 1 == PingThreshold)
                {
                    Message = new StringBuilder("Message: " + ex.Message + "<br/>");

                    if (ex.InnerException != null)
                        Message.Append("Inner Exception: " + ex.InnerException + "<br/>");

                    if (ex.Source != null)
                        Message.Append("Source: " + ex.Source + "<br/>");

                    if (ex.StackTrace != null)
                        Message.Append("Stack Trace" + ex.StackTrace + "<br/>");
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                if (ping != null)
                {
                    ping.Dispose();
                    ping = null;
                }

                if (reply != null)
                {
                    reply = null;
                }

                GC.Collect();
            }
        }

        if (Success)
        {
            WriteToOwnEventLog("Ping Received Successfully", "Ping", true);
        }
        else
        {
            if (status != IPStatus.Unknown && Message != null)
                EmailError("Ping Failed. Returned with a status of " + reply.Status.ToString() + " for site '" + urlToTest + "'. Exception:" + Message);
            else if (status != IPStatus.Unknown && Message == null)
                EmailError("Ping Failed. Returned with a status of " + reply.Status.ToString() + " for site '" + urlToTest + "'.");
            else if (status == IPStatus.Unknown && Message != null)
                EmailError("Ping failed with an exception. <br/>" + Message.ToString());
            else if (status == null && Message == null)
                EmailError("Ping failed. No information available");
            WriteToOwnEventLog("Ping Failed. Email sent", "Ping", true);
        }
    }
    WriteToOwnEventLog("<--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->", "Ping", false);
}

private void CheckDatabase()
{
    foreach(string database in databases)
    {
        bool Success = false;
        StringBuilder Message = null;
        string dbName = "";
        string dbServer = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < DatabaseThreshold; i++)
        {
            SqlConnection conn = null;
            try
            {
                using(conn = new SqlConnection(database))
                {
                    dbName = conn.Database;
                    dbServer = conn.DataSource;
                    WriteToOwnEventLog("Opening Connection to SQL Database " + dbName + " On " + dbServer, "Database", true);
                    conn.Open();
                    Success = true;
                    conn.Close();
                    break;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                LogError(ex);
                if (i + 1 == DatabaseThreshold)
                {
                    Message = new StringBuilder("Message: " + ex.Message + "<br/>");

                    if (ex.InnerException != null)
                        Message.Append("Inner Exception: " + ex.InnerException + "<br/>");

                    if (ex.Source != null)
                        Message.Append("Source: " + ex.Source + "<br/>");

                    if (ex.StackTrace != null)
                        Message.Append("Stack Trace" + ex.StackTrace + "<br/>");
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                if (conn != null)
                {
                    conn.Close();
                    conn.Dispose();
                }

                GC.Collect();
            }
        }

        if (Success)
        {
            WriteToOwnEventLog("SQL Database Connection Successful To " + dbName + " on " + dbServer, "Database", true);
        }
        else
        {
            if (Message != null)
            {
                EmailError("Cannot connect to SQL Database " + dbName + " on " + dbServer + "<br/>" + Message.ToString());
                WriteToOwnEventLog("SQL Database Connection Failed for database " + dbName + " on " + dbServer + ", Email Sent<br>" + Message.ToString(), "Database", true);
            }
            else
            {
                EmailError("Cannot connect to SQL Database " + dbName + " on " + dbServer + ", No information available");
                WriteToOwnEventLog("SQL Database Connection Failed for database " + dbName + " on " + dbServer + ", Email Sent, No information available", "Database", true);
            }
        }
    }

    WriteToOwnEventLog("<--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->", "Database", false);
}
```

Comment: What are you seeing in the logs? Can you step through the code and reproduce?

Comment: Does everything fails or just one of your functions ? like you have ping, db test and HTTP test do they all fail ? With what frequency are you using these ? does your server have firewall ?

Comment: I'm wondering too if it is related to frequency.  Maybe some kind of denial of service filter at the server level, or at the switch/network device level.  Since nothing changes on your end and it starts and stops, likely external to your code.

Comment: I really hope your SQL Server is not open to public ports and your SQL connection check is meant to be executed from inside your firewalls. That said, I second the comment by @unicron.